# Weight training programs

Tags: weight-gain, weighttraining

I've been heavily involved in running over the past few years and now want to bulk up and increase strength and weight.

I've read some questions on here about weight training for beginners however I really wanted to ask - how I should construct a suitable training plan to ensure I am working the key areas?

Essentially I am 185cm and 74kg. I would like to get up to 80kg in a healthy and natural manner. With this I have a strong lower body but a rather week upper body.

How many times a week should I be training? Realistically how long will it take to increase to that weight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How long will it take to increase to that weight ?**
Well, that is not a question anyone can answer. It depends on various considerations like genetics, nutrition and workout intensity.

**How many times a week should I be training**
For a beginner, most experts advises 3 times per week for each muscle group. But it also depends on your workout intensity and your routine.

**Constructing a workout plan**
You can find good workout plans on the internet like [Stronglifts](http://www.stronglifts.com/) which is nearly the most effective online workout plan.

If you want to develop your own routine then you may want to check out [A Workout Routine](http://www.aworkoutroutine.com). This site is really helpful when it comes to building your own routine. It will lead you step by step to build a perfect routine that fits your goals and your current level of fitness. And it will help you to decide how many times a week you should train and how many sets and reps you should do per exercise.

Comment: I'm no fan of beginners creating their own routine, but I'll reserve judgement until I checked out your link. At first glance it looks quite promising.

Answer (score 1):

Starting Strength and Stronglifts 5x5 are good ready made routines. If you want to design your own, Practical Programming for Strength Training by Mark Rippetoe (also the author of Starting Strength) is an often recommended resource.

Comment: It seems to be only a partial answer to the question, perhaps you can add some more detail around the key areas, times per week, time to increase the weight